# Python/SQLite sorting by TEXT date

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

The SQLite documentation says to store dates as TEXT or as sqlite binaries.  So, I thought I'd use str(datetime.datetime.now()).  How would you go about sorting a column by date order when it's stored in TEXT format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO dates are text sortable:

```
>>> datetime.now().isoformat()
'2012-06-16T19:34:05.418407'
>>> sorted([datetime.now().isoformat(), (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=100)).isoformat()])
['2012-03-08T19:34:06.802304', '2012-06-16T19:34:06.802288']
```

Comment: Perfect.  I appreciated the explicit example.

Answer (score 0):

Only [ISO 8601 Time Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) has any chance of being sortable as text and even that's chancy as there are are multiple legal formats.

This is why the [datetime module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) exists, use it.